# How can I take user input within vim for my simple program?

Tags: c, vim, terminal, neovim

New (n)vim user here and am currently wondering how do I take user inputs within vim for my program? This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    c=getchar();
    while (c !=EOF){
        putchar(c);
        c=getchar();
    }
}
```

I am using these commands in my init file to compile and run my code.

```
set makeprg=gcc\ %\ -o\ %<
nnoremap <F11> :w<cr>:make<cr>
nnoremap <F12> :!./%<<cr>
```

Basically when I press F12 I just get a blank result, and not taking any inputs. I know that my program is working since I tried this with vscode and it takes inputs.

Comment: See `:help :term`.

Comment: Just discovered the :term command